# CSS3 Animated Rings

Tags: css, css-animations

Looking for some help on trying to achieve a certain animation. I'm trying to create a sequence similar to the [infinite expanding rings seen here](http://www.motionelements.com/stock-video-1336697-luminance-rings-tunnel). (The example rings are contracting, I'm looking to go the other direction).

I've got a pretty good start thus far, I'm just not sure how to go about making it loop "smoothly", or if it's even possible with only CSS.

Any tips or ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Demo: http://codepen.io/fractionwhole/pen/HljuG

Comment: To loop smoothly all you need to do is make sure that the last keyframe of the animation matches just before the first keyframe of animation.  This will be difficult because the rings are the same width throughout so they scale at the same rate. You can try tapering the width of the rings as you go to the center.  You also need to make sure that a ring is created somehow in the center during the animation to replace the ring that started in the center.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's create 6 rings

```
<div id="r1" class="ring"></div>
<div id="r2" class="ring"></div>
<div id="r3" class="ring"></div>
<div id="r4" class="ring"></div>
<div id="r5" class="ring"></div>
<div id="r6" class="ring"></div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.ring {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 15px gray solid;
    -webkit-animation-name: ani; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: reverse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 0;}
    10% {-webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;}
    99.9% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 1} 
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0} 
}

#r2 { -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;}
#r3 { -webkit-animation-delay: 2s;}
#r4 { -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;}
#r5 { -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;}
#r6 { -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;}
```

The idea is to make the ring appear at minscale, go from min scale to max scale, and then make it disappear.

To make that for n rings, you don't need to create different animations, just reuse the same with an initial delay.

I misread your question and didn't see that you wanted the oposite of the video. I fixed it later setting the animaion in reverse; sorry !

### [webkit demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/EcFDf/)

A better solution:

CSS

```
.ring {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 15px gray solid;
    -webkit-animation-name: ani; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 6s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: normal;

}

@-webkit-keyframes ani {
    0% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.01); opacity: 0} 
    1% {-webkit-transform: scale(0.01); opacity: 1} 
    95% {-webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 0;}
}

#r2 { -webkit-animation-delay: -1s;}
#r3 { -webkit-animation-delay: -2s;}
#r4 { -webkit-animation-delay: -3s;}
#r5 { -webkit-animation-delay: -4s;}
#r6 { -webkit-animation-delay: -5s;}
```

### [new demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vals/EcFDf/2/)

I have changed the keyframes so that now it can run in normal. More important, setting the delays to negative, you can keep the rings separate, but the animation starts right away.

Comment: This is definitely pretty close to what I was looking to accomplish. I was hoping to have the rings already at a set size (a la my starting point code pen). That way on page load there isn't an awkward gap in time while waiting for the rings to fill the screen. This however does meet my request so I'm marking it as the correct answer. I'll keep tweaking it and hopefully get it exactly where I need it. Happy to hear other ideas if you got any as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in addition to scaling you would have to dynamically add smaller rings and attach the css animations to them after a certain period. The larger rings should be removed accordingly.
You will have to use jquery for that. The smaller rings should be id'd properly.

Suppose at t=0 you have 7 rings id'd r1-r7(outwards). When the seventh ring scales out of sight, add another ring inside(with an id of r7) and add animation to it. Repeat this infinitely.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specify that I was looking for a pure CSS solution. I know how I could do this with JS but was trying to push some CSS limits here to see what could/could not be achieved. Thanks for the feedback tho!