# Radiating circle effect using CSS and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

I'm trying to create a radiating circles effect using CSS and Javascript.  My idea was to create a new copy of the circle at an interval, then removing them after a few seconds.

It works well for a couple of seconds, but then it seems like the circles are being removed too quickly, as they do not radiate for more than a moment.

What's happening?  Is there a better way to accomplish the effect that I get for the first couple of seconds?

### CSS

```
.circle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s linear;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.circle.zoom {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transform: none;
}
```

### Javascript

```
counter = 0;

function createCircle(){
  // Circle ID  
  var circleID = "circle_" + counter;

  // Add circle to document
  $("body").append("<div class='circle' id='" + circleID + "'></div>");
  $thisCircle = $("#" + circleID);

  // add "zoom" class
  setTimeout(function(){
      $thisCircle.addClass("zoom");
  },10);

  // Remove circle
  setTimeout(function(){
      $thisCircle.remove();
  },3000);
  counter++;
}

setInterval(function(){
    createCircle();
},500);
```

**JSFiddle Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/YaKBH/9/

Comment: What browser support do you need

Comment: Chrome, Firefox, Safari, IE 10+.

Comment: Looks like it has something to do with the remove circle function.  If you change the settimeout to from 3000 to 30000 it looks much better for a much longer period of time.

Comment: Oh yeah, that must be the issue.  It works for 3 seconds and the timeout is 3000ms.  But I tried to target only the element that was just created for removal, not all of them.

Comment: That's why I am incrementing that counter variable - to create unique IDs and remove only that circle element.

Comment: for a CSS only solution, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17766954/1926369

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to make the `$thisCircle` variable local to your closure scope, it is an implicit global. After the 3 seconds, it will start removing the current circle (that has been animated for 500 ms). The circles 0 to 4 will stay in the DOM, with `opacity: 0`.

To fix this, just add another [`var` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

```
  var $thisCircle = $("#" + circleID);
```

([updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YaKBH/11/))

---

Btw, you could omit that `counter` variable and directly reference the element that was just created:

```
setInterval(function createCircle() {
    var $thisCircle = $("<div class='circle'></div>").appendTo("body");
    // add "zoom" class with minimal delay so the transition starts
    setTimeout(function () {
        $thisCircle.addClass("zoom");
    }, 0);

    // Remove circle
    setTimeout(function () {
        $thisCircle.remove();
    }, 3000);
}, 500);
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YaKBH/14/))

Comment: @PortlandRunner: I don't understand. If you don't remove the circles but add on each half second, they will pile up in the DOM - invisble but allocating memory? That's what I call a leak…

Comment: @Bergi - I removed my comment once I realized how stupid it was... thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better solution.
CSS gives you selectors that allow you to drop the counter altogether.

http://jsfiddle.net/YaKBH/13/

You can append the circle without assigning it an ID.

```
$("body").append("<div class='circle'></div>");
```

Since you want to zoom the circle you just added, it'll be the last circle when you query the circles.

```
$(".circle:last-child").addClass("zoom");
```

When it's time to remove the circle, you're removing the oldest circle, which would be first in queue.

```
$(".circle:first-child").remove();
```

Comment: I'm adding the ID so I can target it, and only it, for removal after three seconds. If append() allowed a callback it wouldn't be necessary but I don't think it does.

Comment: You can target it without an ID though, since you have last child and first child selectors, and you know for a fact you won't be removing a circle that is somewhere in the middle.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this post is old, but in case someone still reaching here like me,  here is CSS only solution.

```css
.circle {  
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 30px;
  background:rgba(24,145,255, 1);
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name:circle;
  opacity:0;
}

.circle2 {  
    animation-delay:1.5s;
}

.circle3 {
    animation-delay:3s;
}
.circle4 {
    animation-delay:4.5s;
}

@keyframes circle {
  0%   {  
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.05);
  opacity:1;
  }  
  100%{  
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  opacity:0;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div class='circle circle1'></div>
<div class='circle circle2'></div>
<div class='circle circle3'></div>
<div class='circle circle4'></div>
```